# Byte[] to float conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter, single-precision

```
Float b = 0.995;
Byte[] a = Bitconverter.GetBytes(b);
```

Now my `byte[]` values are 82 184 126 63 .i.e.,

```
a[0] = 82, a[1] =184, a[2] = 126, and a[3] = 63.
```

I want to revert back above byte to float.So,I used `Bitconverter.Tosingle`

```
Float b = Bitconverter.Tosingle(byte[] value,start index)
```

My doubt is what I need to give `byte[]` value and start index.

Can you pls share as a code along explanation.

Comment: The `floating` tag is to do with CSS... could you give a more appropriate tag, such as the language you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
float val = (float)0.995;
Byte[] arr = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);

float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(arr, 0);
```

Comment: Another way of writing `(float)0.995` is `0.995f`.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is just the byte array that holds the float.
The `startIndex` means the offset with which the conversion function will start reading the 4 bytes that make a float from the passed array. In your case it should just be 0.

Answer (score 0):

[BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[] value, int startIndex)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_ToSingle_System_Byte___System_Int32_)

> **Parameters**
>
> - *value*
>     Byte[]
>     An array of bytes.
> - *startIndex*
>     Int32
>     The starting position within *value*.

The array you get is only 4 bytes long, you need 4 bytes to create the single so position should be 0 - all others give you exceptions:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = 0.995f;
        Byte[] a = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,16:f7}{1,20}\n", b, BitConverter.ToString(a));
        for (var pos = 0; pos < a.Length; pos++)
        {
            try {
                var c = BitConverter.ToSingle(a, pos);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is valid:",pos);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\n",c);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is invalid: {1}",pos,e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
       0.9950000         52-B8-7E-3F

0 is valid:
0.995

1 is invalid: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the 
              items in the collection. Check array index and length.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.BitConverter.ToSingle(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)
   at Program.Main() in d:\Windows\Temp\cowicrki.0.cs:line 13
2 is invalid: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the 
              items in the collection. Check array index and length.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.BitConverter.ToSingle(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)
   at Program.Main() in d:\Windows\Temp\cowicrki.0.cs:line 13
3 is invalid: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the 
              items in the collection. Check array index and length.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.BitConverter.ToSingle(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)
   at Program.Main() in d:\Windows\Temp\cowicrki.0.cs:line 13
```

Comment: I never noticed the method `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` before; it is nice.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen if you want to go from bytes to string, you should use ``System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString( byte[] )``

Comment: @Sealad No, the byte array `{ 0x52, 0xB8, 0x7E, 0x3F, }` represents a value of the single-precision floating point type; it does not represent a text string. I cannot see how that method could make sense. Normally I would do things like `string.Join("-", a.Select(val => $"{val:X2}"))` to get a representation of the contents of the array `a`. But the `BitConverter.ToString` method produces this representation already.